# How to create a new column based on popular string and cluster?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'm trying to create a column that gives the str (column_3 based on the popularity of the str (column_1) and cluster (column_2).

This is the df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column_1' : ['bar', 'club', 'restaurant', 'bar', 'night club', 'store', 'night club', 'bar'], 
    'column_2'  : ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1']
})
```

This is output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column_1' : ['bar', 'club', 'restaurant', 'bar', 'night club', 'store', 'night club', 'bar'], 
    'column_2'  : ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
    'column_3'  : ['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'night club', 'night club', 'night club', 'night club']
})
```

I tried to use transform but with no success.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.Series.map`, but it accepts dict or function. So we first populate a list with `value_counts`, then get popular names in order, then convert to series then to a dict. And, we should convert your `column_2` to int. In short:

```py
df['column_3'] = df['column_2'].astype(int).map(pd.Series(df.column_1.value_counts().index).to_dict())
df['column_3']
>>>
0           bar
1           bar
2           bar
3           bar
4    night club
5    night club
6    night club
7    night club
Name: column_3, dtype: object
```